# Find the direction of the steepest slope?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

My answer for part (a) was ∇g at ($a,b$) = (3$a^2$-6$a$)i + (3$b^2$-12$b$)j

To find the answer to part (b), I solved u = $\frac{∇g}{||∇g||}$ 
= $\frac{-3i-12j}{\sqrt{3^2 + 12^2}}$ = $\frac{-3i-12j}{3\sqrt{17}}$

I think this would be the direction of the steepest descent - and I know that the direction of the steepest ascent would be the negative of this.

So I concluded that the direction of the steepest slope is ±$\frac{-3i-12j}{3\sqrt{17}}$

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Why are the fonts of the $a$'s and $b$'s different in your answer to (a)?  Does that mean something?  If not, it all looks good to me.

Comment: Sorry, the different fonts were an accident - I'll try and edit it now. Thanks for your help :)